# .Net WebSocket Server

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, websocket

Hello WebSocket Server is running successfully.

What do I need to do to send and listen messages right now. Where can I send a message? Do I need to create the client?

I get this code from github: https://github.com/MazyModz/CSharp-WebSocket-Server

Server.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace WebSocketServer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Handler for when a message was received
    /// </summary>
    public class OnMessageReceivedHandler : EventArgs
    {
        /// <summary>The client that send the message</summary>
        private Client _client;

        /// <summary>The message the client sent</summary>
        private string _message;

        /// <summary>Create a new message received event handler</summary>
        /// <param name="Client">The client that sent the message</param>
        /// <param name="Message">The message the client sent</param>
        public OnMessageReceivedHandler(Client Client, string Message)
        {
            this._client = Client;
            this._message = Message;
        }

        /// <summary>Get the client that sent the received message</summary>
        /// <returns>The client that sent the message</returns>
        public Client GetClient()
        {
            return _client;
        }

        /// <summary>The message that was received from the client</summary>
        /// <returns>The received message</returns>
        public string GetMessage()
        {
            return _message;
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handler for when a message was send to a client
    /// </summary>
    public class OnSendMessageHandler : EventArgs
    {
        /// <summary>The client the message was sent to</summary>
        private Client _client;

        /// <summary>The message that was sent to the client</summary>
        private string _message;

        /// <summary>Create a new handler for when a message was sent</summary>
        /// <param name="Client">The client the message was sent to</param>
        /// <param name="Message">The message that was sent to the client</param>
        public OnSendMessageHandler(Client Client, string Message)
        {
            this._client = Client;
            this._message = Message;
        }

        /// <summary>The client the message was sent to</summary>
        /// <returns>The client receiver</returns>
        public Client GetClient()
        {
            return _client;
        }

        /// <summary>The message that was send to the client</summary>
        /// <returns>The sent message</returns>
        public string GetMessage()
        {
            return _message;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handler for when a client connected
    /// </summary>
    public class OnClientConnectedHandler : EventArgs
    {
        /// <summary>The client that connected to the server</summary>
        private Client _client;

        /// <summary>Create a new event handler for when a client connected</summary>
        /// <param name="Client">The client that connected</param>
        public OnClientConnectedHandler(Client Client)
        {
            this._client = Client;
        }

        /// <summary>Get the client that was connected</summary>
        /// <returns>The client that connected </returns>
        public Client GetClient()
        {
            return _client;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handler for when a client disconnects
    /// </summary>
    public class OnClientDisconnectedHandler : EventArgs
    {
        /// <summary>The client that diconnected</summary>
        private Client _client;

        /// <summary>Create a new handler for when a client disconnects</summary>
        /// <param name="Client">The disconnected client</param>
        public OnClientDisconnectedHandler(Client Client)
        {
            this._client = Client;
        }

        /// <summary>Gets the client that disconnected</summary>
        /// <returns>The disconnected client</returns>
        public Client GetClient()
        {
            return _client;
        }
    }

    ///<summary>
    /// Object for all listen servers
    ///</summary>
    public partial class Server
    {
        #region Fields

        /// <summary>The listen socket (server socket)</summary>
        private Socket _socket;

        /// <summary>The listen ip end point of the server</summary>
        private IPEndPoint _endPoint;

        /// <summary>The connected clients to the server </summary>
        private List<Client> _clients = new List<Client>();

        #endregion

        #region Class Events

        /// <summary>Create and start a new listen socket server</summary>
        /// <param name="EndPoint">The listen endpoint of the server</param>
        public Server(IPEndPoint EndPoint)
        {
            // Set the endpoint if the input is valid
            if (EndPoint == null) return;
            this._endPoint = EndPoint;

            // Create a new listen socket
            this._socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            Console.WriteLine("WebSocket Sunucu Başlatıldı.\nListening on {0}:{1}\n", GetEndPoint().Address.ToString(), GetEndPoint().Port);

            // Start the server
            start();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Field Getters

        /// <summary>Gets the listen socket</summary>
        /// <returns>The listen socket</returns>
        public Socket GetSocket()
        {
            return _socket;
        }

        /// <summary>Get the listen socket endpoint</summary>
        /// <returns>The listen socket endpoint</returns>
        public IPEndPoint GetEndPoint()
        {
            return _endPoint;
        }

        /// <summary>Gets a connected client at the given index</summary>
        /// <param name="Index">The connected client array index</param>
        /// <returns>The connected client at the index, returns null if the index is out of bounds</returns>
        public Client GetConnectedClient(int Index)
        {
            if (Index < 0 || Index >= _clients.Count) return null;
            return _clients[Index];
        }

        /// <summary>Gets a connected client with the given guid</summary>
        /// <param name="Guid">The Guid of the client to get</param>
        /// <returns>The client with the given id, return null if no client with the guid could be found</returns>
        public Client GetConnectedClient(string Guid)
        {
            foreach(Client client in _clients)
            {
                if (client.GetGuid() == Guid) return client;
            }
            return null;
        }

        /// <summary>Gets a connected client with the given socket</summary>
        /// <param name="Socket">The socket of the client </param>
        /// <returns>The connected client with the given socket, returns null if no client with the socket was found</returns>
        public Client GetConnectedClient(Socket Socket)
        {
            foreach(Client client in _clients)
            {
                if (client.GetSocket() == Socket) return client;
            }
            return null;
        }

        /// <summary>Get the number of clients that are connected to the server</summary>
        /// <returns>The number of connected clients</returns>
        public int GetConnectedClientCount()
        {
            return _clients.Count;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the listen server when a server object is created
        /// </summary>
        private void start()
        {
            // Bind the socket and start listending
            GetSocket().Bind(GetEndPoint());
            GetSocket().Listen(0);

            // Start to accept clients and accept incomming connections 
            GetSocket().BeginAccept(connectionCallback, null);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops the listen server 
        /// </summary>
        public void Stop()
        {
            GetSocket().Close();
            GetSocket().Dispose();
        }

        /// <summary>Called when the socket is trying to accept an incomming connection</summary>
        /// <param name="AsyncResult">The async operation state</param>
        private void connectionCallback(IAsyncResult AsyncResult)
        {
            try
            {
                // Gets the client thats trying to connect to the server
                Socket clientSocket = GetSocket().EndAccept(AsyncResult);

                // Read the handshake updgrade request
                byte[] handshakeBuffer = new byte[1024];
                int handshakeReceived = clientSocket.Receive(handshakeBuffer);

                // Get the hanshake request key and get the hanshake response
                string requestKey = Helpers.GetHandshakeRequestKey(Encoding.Default.GetString(handshakeBuffer));
                string hanshakeResponse = Helpers.GetHandshakeResponse(Helpers.HashKey(requestKey));

                // Send the handshake updgrade response to the connecting client 
                clientSocket.Send(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(hanshakeResponse));

                // Create a new client object and add 
                // it to the list of connected clients
                Client client = new Client(this, clientSocket);
                _clients.Add(client);

                // Call the event when a client has connected to the listen server 
                if (OnClientConnected == null) throw new Exception("Server error: event OnClientConnected is not bound!");
                OnClientConnected(this, new OnClientConnectedHandler(client));

                // Start to accept incomming connections again 
                GetSocket().BeginAccept(connectionCallback, null);

            }
            catch (Exception Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error has occured while trying to accept a connecting client.\n\n{0}", Exception.Message);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Called when a message was recived, calls the OnMessageReceived event</summary>
        /// <param name="Client">The client that sent the message</param>
        /// <param name="Message">The message that the client sent</param>
        public void ReceiveMessage(Client Client, string Message)
        {
            if (OnMessageReceived == null) throw new Exception("Server error: event OnMessageReceived is not bound!");
            OnMessageReceived(this, new OnMessageReceivedHandler(Client, Message));
        }

        /// <summary>Called when a client disconnectes, calls event OnClientDisconnected</summary>
        /// <param name="Client">The client that disconnected</param>
        public void ClientDisconnect(Client Client)
        {
            // Remove the client from the connected clients list
            _clients.Remove(Client);

            // Call the OnClientDisconnected event
            if (OnClientDisconnected == null) throw new Exception("Server error: OnClientDisconnected is not bound!");
            OnClientDisconnected(this, new OnClientDisconnectedHandler(Client));
        }

        #endregion

        #region Server Events

        /// <summary>Send a message to a connected client</summary>
        /// <param name="Client">The client to send the data to</param>
        /// <param name="Data">The data to send the client</param>
        public void SendMessage(Client Client, string Data)
        {
            // Create a websocket frame around the data to send
            byte[] frameMessage = Helpers.GetFrameFromString(Data);

            // Send the framed message to the in client
            Client.GetSocket().Send(frameMessage);

            // Call the on send message callback event 
            if (OnSendMessage == null) throw new Exception("Server error: event OnSendMessage is not bound!");
            OnSendMessage(this, new OnSendMessageHandler(Client, Data));
        }

        /// <summary>Called after a message was sent</summary>
        public event EventHandler<OnSendMessageHandler> OnSendMessage;

        /// <summary>Called when a client was connected to the server (after handshake)</summary>
        public event EventHandler<OnClientConnectedHandler> OnClientConnected;

        /// <summary>Called when a message was received from a connected client</summary>
        public event EventHandler<OnMessageReceivedHandler> OnMessageReceived;

        /// <summary>Called when a client disconnected</summary>
        public event EventHandler<OnClientDisconnectedHandler> OnClientDisconnected;

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Client.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace WebSocketServer
{
    ///<summary>
    /// Object for all connectecd clients
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Client
    {

        #region Fields

        ///<summary>The socket of the connected client</summary>
        private Socket _socket;

        ///<summary>The guid of the connected client</summary>
        private string _guid;

        /// <summary>The server that the client is connected to</summary>
        private Server _server;

        /// <summary>If the server has sent a ping to the client and is waiting for a pong</summary>
        private bool _bIsWaitingForPong;

        #endregion

        #region Class Events

        /// <summary>Create a new object for a connected client</summary>
        /// <param name="Server">The server object instance that the client is connected to</param>
        /// <param name="Socket">The socket of the connected client</param>
        public Client(Server Server, Socket Socket)
        {
            this._server = Server;
            this._socket = Socket;
            this._guid = Helpers.CreateGuid("client");

            // Start to detect incomming messages 
            GetSocket().BeginReceive(new byte[] { 0 }, 0, 0, SocketFlags.None, messageCallback, null);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Field Getters

        /// <summary>Gets the guid of the connected client</summary>
        /// <returns>The GUID of the client</returns>
        public string GetGuid()
        {
            return _guid;
        }

        ///<summary>Gets the socket of the connected client</summary>
        ///<returns>The socket of the client</return>
        public Socket GetSocket()
        {
            return _socket;
        }

        /// <summary>The socket that this client is connected to</summary>
        /// <returns>Listen socket</returns>
        public Server GetServer()
        {
            return _server;
        }

        /// <summary>Gets if the server is waiting for a pong response</summary>
        /// <returns>If the server is waiting for a pong response</returns>
        public bool GetIsWaitingForPong()
        {
            return _bIsWaitingForPong;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Field Setters

        /// <summary>Sets if the server is waiting for a pong response</summary>
        /// <param name="bIsWaitingForPong">If the server is waiting for a pong response</param>
        public void SetIsWaitingForPong(bool bIsWaitingForPong)
        {
            _bIsWaitingForPong = bIsWaitingForPong;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        /// <summary>Called when a message was received from the client</summary>
        private void messageCallback(IAsyncResult AsyncResult)
        {
            try
            {
                GetSocket().EndReceive(AsyncResult);

                // Read the incomming message 
                byte[] messageBuffer = new byte[8];
                int bytesReceived = GetSocket().Receive(messageBuffer);

                // Resize the byte array to remove whitespaces 
                if (bytesReceived < messageBuffer.Length) Array.Resize<byte>(ref messageBuffer, bytesReceived);

                // Get the opcode of the frame
                EOpcodeType opcode = Helpers.GetFrameOpcode(messageBuffer);

                // If the connection was closed
                if(opcode == EOpcodeType.ClosedConnection)
                {
                    GetServer().ClientDisconnect(this);
                    return;
                }

                // Pass the message to the server event to handle the logic
                GetServer().ReceiveMessage(this, Helpers.GetDataFromFrame(messageBuffer));

                // Start to receive messages again
                GetSocket().BeginReceive(new byte[] { 0 }, 0, 0, SocketFlags.None, messageCallback, null);

            }
            catch(Exception Exception)
            {
                GetSocket().Close();
                GetSocket().Dispose();
                GetServer().ClientDisconnect(this);
            }
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

Program.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WebSocketServer
{
    class Program
    {
        // Example application for the websocker server
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create a listen server on localhost with port 80
            Server server = new Server(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 80));

            /*
             * Bind required events for the server
             */

            server.OnClientConnected += (object sender, OnClientConnectedHandler e) => 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Client with GUID: {0} Connected!", e.GetClient().GetGuid());
            };

            server.OnClientDisconnected += (object sender, OnClientDisconnectedHandler e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Client {0} Disconnected", e.GetClient().GetGuid());
            };

            server.OnMessageReceived += (object sender, OnMessageReceivedHandler e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Received Message: '{1}' from client: {0}", e.GetClient().GetGuid(), e.GetMessage());
            };

            server.OnSendMessage += (object sender, OnSendMessageHandler e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sent message: '{0}' to client {1}", e.GetMessage(), e.GetClient().GetGuid());
            };

            // Close the application only when the close button is clicked
            Process.GetCurrentProcess().WaitForExit();
        }
    }
}
```

Helpers.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace WebSocketServer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Holds data for a encoded message frame
    /// </summary>
    public struct SFrameMaskData
    {
        public int DataLength, KeyIndex, TotalLenght;
        public EOpcodeType Opcode;

        public SFrameMaskData(int DataLength, int KeyIndex, int TotalLenght, EOpcodeType Opcode)
        {
            this.DataLength = DataLength;
            this.KeyIndex = KeyIndex;
            this.TotalLenght = TotalLenght;
            this.Opcode = Opcode;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Enum for opcode types
    /// </summary>
    public enum EOpcodeType
    {
        /* Denotes a continuation code */
        Fragment = 0,

        /* Denotes a text code */
        Text = 1,

        /* Denotes a binary code */
        Binary = 2,

        /* Denotes a closed connection */
        ClosedConnection = 8,

        /* Denotes a ping*/
        Ping = 9,

        /* Denotes a pong */
        Pong = 10
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Helper methods for the Server and Client class
    /// </summary>
    public static class Helpers
    {
        /// <summary>Gets data for a encoded websocket frame message</summary>
        /// <param name="Data">The data to get the info from</param>
        /// <returns>The frame data</returns>
        public static SFrameMaskData GetFrameData(byte[] Data)
        {
            // Get the opcode of the frame
            int opcode = Data[0] - 128;

            // If the length of the message is in the 2 first indexes
            if (Data[1] - 128 <= 125)
            {
                int dataLength = (Data[1] - 128);
                return new SFrameMaskData(dataLength, 2, dataLength + 6, (EOpcodeType)opcode);
            }

            // If the length of the message is in the following two indexes
            if (Data[1] - 128 == 126)
            {
                // Combine the bytes to get the length
                int dataLength = BitConverter.ToInt16(new byte[] { Data[3], Data[2] }, 0);
                return new SFrameMaskData(dataLength, 4, dataLength + 8, (EOpcodeType)opcode);
            }

            // If the data length is in the following 8 indexes
            if (Data[1] - 128 == 127)
            {
                // Get the following 8 bytes to combine to get the data 
                byte[] combine = new byte[8];
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) combine[i] = Data[i + 2];

                // Combine the bytes to get the length
                //int dataLength = (int)BitConverter.ToInt64(new byte[] { Data[9], Data[8], Data[7], Data[6], Data[5], Data[4], Data[3], Data[2] }, 0);
                int dataLength = (int)BitConverter.ToInt64(combine, 0);
                return new SFrameMaskData(dataLength, 10, dataLength + 14, (EOpcodeType)opcode);
            }

            // error
            return new SFrameMaskData(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        /// <summary>Gets the opcode of a frame</summary>
        /// <param name="Frame">The frame to get the opcode from</param>
        /// <returns>The opcode of the frame</returns>
        public static EOpcodeType GetFrameOpcode(byte[] Frame)
        {
            return (EOpcodeType)Frame[0] - 128;
        }

        /// <summary>Gets the decoded frame data from the given byte array</summary>
        /// <param name="Data">The byte array to decode</param>
        /// <returns>The decoded data</returns>
        public static string GetDataFromFrame(byte[] Data)
        {
            // Get the frame data
            SFrameMaskData frameData = GetFrameData(Data);

            // Get the decode frame key from the frame data
            byte[] decodeKey = new byte[4];
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) decodeKey[i] = Data[frameData.KeyIndex + i];

            int dataIndex = frameData.KeyIndex + 4;
            int count = 0;

            // Decode the data using the key
            for (int i = dataIndex; i < frameData.TotalLenght; i++)
            {
                Data[i] = (byte)(Data[i] ^ decodeKey[count % 4]);
                count++;
            }

            // Return the decoded message 
            return Encoding.Default.GetString(Data, dataIndex, frameData.DataLength);
        }

        /// <summary>Checks if a byte array is valid</summary>
        /// <param name="Buffer">The byte array to check</param>
        /// <returns>'true' if the byte array is valid</returns>
        public static bool GetIsBufferValid(ref byte[] Buffer)
        {
            if (Buffer == null) return false;
            if (Buffer.Length <= 0) return false;

            return true;
        }

        /// <summary>Gets an encoded websocket frame to send to a client from a string</summary>
        /// <param name="Message">The message to encode into the frame</param>
        /// <param name="Opcode">The opcode of the frame</param>
        /// <returns>Byte array in form of a websocket frame</returns>
        public static byte[] GetFrameFromString(string Message, EOpcodeType Opcode = EOpcodeType.Text)
        {
            byte[] response;
            byte[] bytesRaw = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Message);
            byte[] frame = new byte[10];

            int indexStartRawData = -1;
            int length = bytesRaw.Length;

            frame[0] = (byte)(128 + (int)Opcode);
            if (length <= 125)
            {
                frame[1] = (byte)length;
                indexStartRawData = 2;
            }
            else if (length >= 126 && length <= 65535)
            {
                frame[1] = (byte)126;
                frame[2] = (byte)((length >> 8) & 255);
                frame[3] = (byte)(length & 255);
                indexStartRawData = 4;
            }
            else
            {
                frame[1] = (byte)127;
                frame[2] = (byte)((length >> 56) & 255);
                frame[3] = (byte)((length >> 48) & 255);
                frame[4] = (byte)((length >> 40) & 255);
                frame[5] = (byte)((length >> 32) & 255);
                frame[6] = (byte)((length >> 24) & 255);
                frame[7] = (byte)((length >> 16) & 255);
                frame[8] = (byte)((length >> 8) & 255);
                frame[9] = (byte)(length & 255);

                indexStartRawData = 10;
            }

            response = new byte[indexStartRawData + length];

            int i, reponseIdx = 0;

            //Add the frame bytes to the reponse
            for (i = 0; i < indexStartRawData; i++)
            {
                response[reponseIdx] = frame[i];
                reponseIdx++;
            }

            //Add the data bytes to the response
            for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                response[reponseIdx] = bytesRaw[i];
                reponseIdx++;
            }

            return response;
        }

        /// <summary>Hash a request key with SHA1 to get the response key</summary>
        /// <param name="Key">The request key</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string HashKey(string Key)
        {
            const string handshakeKey = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
            string longKey = Key + handshakeKey;

            SHA1 sha1 = SHA1.Create();
            byte[] hashBytes = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(longKey));

            return Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
        }

        /// <summary>Gets the http request string to send to the websocket client</summary>
        /// <param name="Key">The SHA1 hashed key to respond with</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string GetHandshakeResponse(string Key)
        {
            return string.Format("HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\nUpgrade: WebSocket\nConnection: Upgrade\nSec-WebSocket-Accept: {0}\r\n\r\n", Key);
        }

        /// <summary>Gets the WebSocket handshake updgrade key from the http request</summary>
        /// <param name="HttpRequest">The http request string to get the key from</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string GetHandshakeRequestKey(string HttpRequest)
        {
            int keyStart = HttpRequest.IndexOf("Sec-WebSocket-Key: ") + 19;
            string key = null;

            for (int i = keyStart; i < (keyStart + 24); i++)
            {
                key += HttpRequest[i];
            }
            return key;
        }

        /// <summary>Creates a random guid with a prefix</summary>
        /// <param name="Prefix">The prefix of the id; null = no prefix</param>
        /// <param name="Length">The length of the id to generate</param>
        /// <returns>The random guid. Ex. Prefix-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</returns>
        public static string CreateGuid(string Prefix, int Length = 16)
        {
            string final = null;
            string ids = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

            Random random = new Random();

            // Loop and get a random index in the ids and append to id 
            for (short i = 0; i < Length; i++) final += ids[random.Next(0, ids.Length)];

            // Return the guid without a prefix
            if (Prefix == null) return final;

            // Return the guid with a prefix
            return string.Format("{0}-{1}", Prefix, final);
        }
    }
}
```

My code block is like this, there are 4 files. Program, Helpers, Client, Server

I didn't know what to do.

Comment: Where did you get this code?

Comment: I get this code from github

Comment: `1.` put the link to the repository into the question `2.` try to ask the author of the repository first

Comment: Ok i added the link.

Comment: Why did you get the code from the repository where the last commit has been added 7 years ago? I suggest you to use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Using the Fleck nuget package can easily help you implement WebSocket communication